# Import values from others spreadsheets to a single one

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm having some trouble to import data values from many spreadsheets to a single one. I need to import all the values from all columns "A" of each spreadsheets to the column "A" of a new one. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=lambda( 
  spreadsheetIds, rangeA1, header, 
  query( 
    reduce( 
      header, spreadsheetIds, 
      lambda( 
        result, id, 
        { 
          result; 
          iferror(importrange(id, rangeA1), header) 
        } 
      ) 
    ), 
    "where Col1 is not null", 1 
  ) 
)( 
  { "...put spreadsheet id here...", "...and here...", "...and here..." }, 
  "Data!A2:A", 
  "Imported" 
)
```

Comment: it don't work :S thanks for your comments :S

Comment: Edited the answer. Make sure you have [authorized](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?visit_id=638098003054890574-1032217142&rd=1#zippy=%2Cpermission-access) the imports.

Comment: Yes I do but it shows "Imported" on cells :S sorry I'm not even sure if I did it right :S

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet where the issue can be reproduced. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.